# C#: Is data type the same as type?

Tags: c#, types

maybe its silly but I am not sure if there is difference between types and data types

`int` is data type

```
class A{}
```

A is type or data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "data type" in any .NET language. "Data type" is often used to clarify "type" to refer to the actual runtime type of the variable rather than a more abstract notion of what "kind" of value is present.

`int` is what's referred to as a *value type*. All primitive types (`int`, `double`, `char`, etc.) are value types, with the exception of `string`, which is a reference type (though, like value types, it's immutable).

Any object declared as a `class` is a *reference type*. Any object declared as a `struct` is a *value type*.

Answer (score 7):

Actually in .NET there are reference types and value types. Value types are `enum` or `struct` and reference types are `class`.

`int` is an alias to [System.Int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) which is a struct and so value type, while in your case `A` is class, so reference type.

Comment: That is an important difference to understand, but "data type" and "type" refer to the same concept.

Comment: Reference types are nullable, and value type are not.

Comment: @controlbreak: C# 3.0 introduced nullable value types. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx): "Nullable types represent value-type variables that can be assigned the value of null."

Comment: And let's not forget that at least five geese are referred to as a "Gaggle".

Comment: @0xA3: Technically, .NET 2.0 introduced the concept of generics, which added the `Nullable<T>` structure. Syntactic sugar in VB.NET and C# starting with VS 2005 allowed for assignment and comparison to "null" (though it does not actually assign a null value to the struct, and comparison to null just checks the `HasValue` property).

Comment: I love the "??" in c# :)
string PerhapsThisIsNull = null;
string myText = PerhapsThisIsNull ?? "Hey it's null!";

Comment: @Adam Robinson: Thanks for the additional info. I didn't want to repeat all the details about nullable types in my comment. Of course, the struct itself is technically not null, sorry if this caused any confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Same thing

Answer (score 0):

Same thing, just think of it as Type. To be specific, A in your example is a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

`A` is a type that can have properties/member variables which can be of other types or data types (`int`,`string`)

But then, in terms of framework everything is a type (reference or value).

Answer (score 0):

From the C# Spec Section 1.3

> 1.3 Types and variables
>
> There are two kinds of types in C#: ***value types*** and ***reference
> types***. Variables of value types
> directly contain their data whereas
> variables of reference types store
> references to their data, the latter
> being known as objects. With reference
> types, it is possible for two
> variables to reference the same object
> and thus possible for operations on
> one variable to affect the object
> referenced by the other variable. With
> value types, the variables each have
> their own copy of the data, and it is
> not possible for operations on one to
> affect the other (except in the case
> of ref and out parameter variables).
>
> C#’s value types are further divided into ***simple types, enum
> types, struct types,*** and
> ***nullable types***, and C#’s reference types are further divided
> into ***class types, interface types,
> array types***, and ***delegate
> types***.

and int is a value type that is also a simple type and is also a Signed integral

class a{} is a reference type that is a class type that is user defined.